# Wrong app comes to front after using mission control

Tags: mac, mission-control, gesture

I've been having this issue for a while now. I cant remember if it was a problem when I was using Mavericks, but I've only noticed it using Sierra.

Every time I initiate mission control (using either F3 or Three finger gesture upwards), if I click on a window, or even just want to return to the original window I was on, another open window comes to the front.

This issue is extremely frustrating, as I almost always end up having to click on the window I was originally on when I see it behind the other window that comes up.

I am using a Macbook Pro Early 2015 on MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.1

Comment: It appears that nobody could give you any solution to this problem of Mission Control. I seem to have isolated the problem, but have however not found a solution. The problem only happens when I have Safari open.
Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: It seems to happen anytime I click on Safari or Google Chrome. Has anyone found a solution to this? It is extremely frustrating. I can't understand why Apple hasn't addressed/fixed this yet.